# Change sprintf into simple UNION

Tags: php, mysql

```
$STH_1 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT table_name                        
                         FROM information_schema.tables                        
                        WHERE table_name                        
                         LIKE 'v_c_ei\_9%'
                         ");
$stmts_1 = array();

while (($row_1 = $STH_1 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){

$table_name = $row_1['table_name'];
$stmts_1[] = sprintf("SELECT *  
                        FROM $table_name
                       WHERE (ei_code = '1117') AND (DAY(date_time) != '00') 

                     "); 

} 

$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1);  
$stmt_1 .= "\nORDER BY date_time ASC";  

$STH_5_2 = $DBH_R->query($stmt_1);

while (($row_5_2 = $STH_5_2 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){
```

OK, the script above is working ok. But, I want (must) change its functionality. I must do selection before UNION (something like ORDER BY ... LIMIT) but I know - this is not working. The solution is to change sprintif into UNION & UNION & UNION ... But the problem is - we don't know how much tables we have.

The table names from the first query looks like

```
v_c_ei_9001
v_c_ei_9002
..........
v_c_ei_9030
..........
ect.
```

Than the q: how change the sprintif (and maybe array $stmts_1 too) from abowe into the UNION in situation when we don't know how much tables we have?
thnks

Comment: If you're regularly adding new tables of a known structure, it sounds like your database needs normalising.  You ought to only have one such table, with a column to indicate whatever differentiates between them.

Comment: the every table have informations for products for concrete country. We have tables for every country from our structure (offer ect.). But at this moment we don't know how much tables (countries) we have.

Comment: As I suggested, you'd be better off with a single products table that has a `country` column.

Comment: so, it should be just one table with a country field.

Comment: In a OLTP environment, yes. In a data warehousing environment, not necessarily.

Comment: guys, please, don't change the subject of the problem. At this moment the dbase structure is optimal - every tables have near 7-10k rows, the country name is coding into table name (9001, 9002 ect). Please, try to help in the presented problem ...

Comment: yes, generaly we can view this tables like a warehouse of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses to each constituent of the `UNION`, as follows:

```
while (($row_1 = $STH_1 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){

$table_name = $row_1['table_name'];
$stmts_1[] = sprintf("SELECT *  
                      FROM $table_name
                      WHERE (ei_code = '1117') AND (DAY(date_time) != '00')
                      ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1 
                     "); 

}
```

And then you do the following:

```
$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1);  
$stmt_1 .= "\nORDER BY date_time ASC";                   // <---- remember this bit
```

The resulting string in `$stmt_1` will look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM v_c_ei_9001
WHERE (ei_code = '1117') AND (DAY(date_time) != '00')
ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT *
FROM v_c_ei_9030
WHERE (ei_code = '1117') AND (DAY(date_time) != '00')
ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1
ORDER BY date_time ASC                                 -- it's appearing down here!
```

As you can see, the final constituent of your `UNION` has **two** `ORDER BY` clauses, which is a syntax error.  Either remove the line commented `remember this bit` above, or else (if you need to reorder the unified queries) you must make the `UNION` a subquery to an outer query that performs the reordering:

```
$stmt_1 = "SELECT * FROM ("
$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1);  
$stmt_1 .= ") ORDER BY date_time ASC";
```

Comment: thank you for your help and show the right way of construct the soluction of problem. But .. 1. I change a main query as you show 2. at remember point - I do as you show => I have "parse error" in line $stmt_1 .=implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1); 3. at remember point - I use only one line of code => $stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1); and I have the info: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in line while (($row_5_2 ..... .

Comment: @Andrew: The first three blocks of code in my answer are an explanation of why your code wasn't working.  The fourth (and final) block is what you should be doing instead.  Is that what you're trying?

Comment: ok. at point 2 -> you don't remember about ";" at the end of the line. Now the info is as in point 3.

Comment: as I understand your lesson - if I want to have 2x order than I must change the code like in your 4 block. I did do it. I add first ORDER BY LIMIT 1 into the main query and I change the rest as you show in your 4-th block. At the and - as I see - the main query cant give any solution. hmm .... it's so no logical :))))

Comment: at this moment - when I delete ORDERBY..LIMIT 1 from main query .. it's not working (the rest of code is changed like in 4th block)

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the simple way to show itself is write whatever, instead consider the solution of the problem. The situation is similar to evaluating questions - if the complexity of the problem is beyond the involvement of the viewer it is easier to evaluate them negatively than actually help the man who asks. And not just speak, instead of writing anything.

For all those who may face such a problem I give operating solution.

The simplest overall solution was to specify the tables on which the main query is executed. What was to be obtained in the main query by ORDER BY was obtained first auxiliary request on the first query by pre-rank the tables on the main query is executed.

In this way we avoid the problem 2x ORDER BY in the main query, because the ORDER BY clause is transferred to the first auxiliary request.

```
$STH_1 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT c.table_name 
                          FROM v_c_country c 
                    INNER JOIN information_schema.tables i ON i.table_name = c.table_name 
                      ORDER BY c.country_name_pl ASC                                      ");

while (($row_1 = $STH_1 -> fetch_assoc()) != null){


$table_name = $row_1['table_name'];

$stmts_1[] = sprintf("SELECT *,'$table_name' AS table_name, time(date_time) AS time_dt, date(date_time) AS date_dt, MAX(date_time) AS MAXdate  
                        FROM $table_name
                       WHERE ei_code = '1117' AND (DAY(date_time) != '00') 
AND date_time = (SELECT MAX(date_time) FROM $table_name WHERE ei_code = '1117' AND index_released = '1')
                  "); 

}


$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1); 

$STH_5_2 = $DBH_R->query($stmt_1);
```

Often I meet here with the tolerant approach to the questions asked, you know that if someone asks a question that awaits us - looking for - ask for help in solving the problem. I really, really thank all those who reach out a helping hand and give really helpful answer. These people really do happen.